# "Invalid use of incomplete type" in basic Hunter/Prey exercise

Tags: c++

So my current assignment is to make a basic Hunter and Prey simulation, and after having several other issues my professor advised that I just put everything in `main.cpp` to actually get the thing working for now.

My current issue is that in the `Creature::Find()` function it's claiming that the `Grid` class is incomplete even though it's pre-declared at the top of the file.  My initial thought was to place the `Grid` class before `Creature`, but this causes a lot more or the same error (referring to `Creature` being incomplete) since `Grid` is essentially a 2D array of `Creature` pointers.  Below is the relevant bits of the code, the whole file can be found on Dropbox [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ehu4geckwufr6bo/main.cpp).

---

```
class Grid;  //*** error: forward declaration of 'class Grid'

//Other stuff...

class Creature
{
public:
    Grid* theGrid;
    Coords position;
    int stepBreed;
    int stepHunger;
    char face;
    bool hasMoved;

    Creature(Grid* _grid, Coords _position, char _face)  //Constructor
    {
        theGrid = _grid;
        position = _position;
        face = _face;
        stepBreed = stepHunger = 0;
        hasMoved = false;
    }

    vector<Coords> Find(char thisFace)  //Returns a list of coords with prey on them
    {
        vector<Coords> result;
        for(int i = position.x-1; i <= position.x+1; i++)
            for(int j = position.y-1; j <= position.y+1; j++)
            {
                Coords temp(i,j);
                if(theGrid->Occupant(temp) == thisFace) //*** error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Grid'
                    result.push_back(temp);
            }
        return result;
    }

    virtual Coords Move() = 0;  //Allows the creature type to define it's own movement
    virtual Coords Breed() = 0;  //Allows the creature type to define it's own breeding
    virtual bool Starve() = 0;  //Allows the creature type to starve of its own accord
};

class Grid
{
public:
    Creature* grid[MAX_X][MAX_Y];

    Grid() //Initalizes the grid and spawns random creatures
    {
        cout<<endl<<"grid init"<<endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_X; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < MAX_Y; j++)
                grid[i][j] = NULL;
    }

    void Move() //Tells each creature on the grid to move
    {
        cout<<endl<<"---  Grid::Move() TOP  ---"<<endl<<endl;
        ResetMoved();

        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_X; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < MAX_Y; j++)
                if(grid[i][j])
                    grid[i][j]->Move();
        cout<<endl<<"---  Grid::Move() BOTTOM  ---"<<endl<<endl;
    }

    void Breed() //Tells each creature to breed (if it can)
    {

    }

    void Kill()  //Tells each creature to die (if it's old)
    {

    }

    char** Snapshot()  //Creates a char array "snapshot" of the board
    {
        char** result = new char*[MAX_X];
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_X; i++)
        {
            result[i] = new char[MAX_Y];
            for(int j = 0; j < MAX_Y; j++)
            {
                result[i][j] = Occupant(Coords(i, j));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    Creature* Get(Coords here)  //Returns a pointer to the object at the specified position
    {
        return grid[here.x][here.y];
    }

    char Occupant(Coords here) //Returns the character of the specified position
    {
        if(!Get(here))
            return FACE_EMPTY;
        return Get(here)->face;
    }

    void Clear(Coords here)  //Deletes the object at the specified position
    {
        cout<<endl<<"---  Grid::Clear() TOP  ---"<<endl<<endl;

        if(!Get(here))
        {
            cout<<"   inside if"<<endl;
            delete Get(here);
        }
        cout<<"   outside if"<<endl;
        grid[here.x][here.y] = NULL;

        cout<<endl<<"---  Grid::Clear() BOTTOM  ---"<<endl<<endl;
    }

    void ResetMoved()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_X; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < MAX_Y; j++)
                if(grid[i][j])
                    grid[i][j]->hasMoved = false;
    }
};
```

EDIT: The preview and markup toolbar isn't working for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular dependency (I seem to remember you had this question before). Putting things in the same file doesn't really solve the problem (although perhaps it helps you see the problem a little more clearly). What you have to do is order things correctly so that every function is defined after the classes it needs.

In this case I would do it like this

```
class Grid;

class Creature
{
public:
    Grid* theGrid;
    ...
    vector<Coords> Find(char thisFace);
    ...
};

class Grid
{
public:
    Creature* grid[MAX_X][MAX_Y];
    ...
};

vector<Coords> Creature::Find(char thisFace)
{
   ...
}
```

`Creature::Find` needs both the `Creature` class (obviously) and the `Grid` class, so it must go after both classes have been fully defined.

If you end up putting the `Creature::Find` definition in a header file then you must add the `inline` keyword, otherwise you'll get multiple definitions.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about making a new question for a similar topic, wasn't sure if it warranted it.  I was getting unresolved externals on various functions and the professor couldn't figure out why either, that's why he had me put it all in the main.   I thought the pre-declaration of Grid was supposed to prevent stuff like this, or does that only work for the definitions?

Comment: @Farlo No, the pre-declaration (usually called a forward declaration) tells the compiler that Grid is a class, so (for instance) `Grid* theGrid;` is legal. But a forward declaration doesn't tell the compiler anything *about* the class. So `theGrid->Occupant(temp)` is not legal even after a forward declaration, because the forward declaration doesn't tell the compiler that Grid has a method called Occupant

Comment: @Farlo A problem you can usually avoid by ensuring the *implementation* of any code that uses incomplete types follows a declaration that completes the type. In this case there is nothing stopping you from moving the implementation of `Creature::Find` method out-of-class (just declare it as a member, don't implement it in-class) and implement it *after* the formal definition of `Grid`. And +1 on the answer.

Comment: Ah, makes sense.  I'm assuming that's the reason, aside from tidiness, that classes are split into headers and cpp files?  

If I decide to break everything back out into separate files, can you think of any reason I'd be getting unresolved externals even though the function "titles" are identical (plus the scope resolution operator of course)?

EDIT: @WhozCraig Thanks for the comment, unfortunately I can't +1 until I get some reputation, otherwise I would.

Comment: Most common reason we see round here for unresolveds in projects that have been separated into multiple files is that people forget to compile all the files they need to. I suppose the other possible reason would be inconsistent declarations and definitions in the different files. Nothing else occurs to me immediately. I think your prof's advice was good, get it working in a single file. And then *gradually* move it back to multiple files if that's what you want. Don't try to move everything at once.

Answer (score 0):

Forward declaration is fine for declaring a pointer. However the compiler doesn't know what your forward declared class contains yet. So you can't expect it to allow something like

```
class Grid;
//
theGrid->Occupant(temp)
```

---

You need to either include the file which contains the whole definition of Grid. OR **you can move the definition of the `Creature::find` function in to another file where Grid.h is included. For example in `Grid.cpp`**

Comment: It need not be moved to another file, and certainly not moved to a file utterly unrelated by name. So long as code that utilizes what was an incomplete type during declaration *follows* the formal declaration to complete the type, it will work, even in the same source file.

Comment: @WhozCraig I have said that he can include the file which contains the whole definition of Grid. I don't know what you mean?

Comment: @WhozCraig and whether the file name is relevant or not is not up to me to decide. That is just an **example**. it says for example right there.